# New handling of Access Tokens in JupyterHub 2.0.0?

Tags: docker, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab, jupyterhub

I have a containerized platform covered with some integration tests. Jupyter Containers are spawned for each user. There is a relatively simple python test implemented which communicates with jupyter via REST API and creates a folder. Basically it's logging in, extracts token from the page data and uses this token for the next call to create a directory. It looks like this:

```py
class TokenParser(HTMLParser):
    """
    Small parser to extract Jupyter Access Token.
    """
    def __init__(self):
        self.jupyter_token = None
        super().__init__()

    def handle_data(self, data):
        jupyter_data = {}
        try:
            if self.jupyter_token is None:
                jupyter_data = json.loads(data)
                self.jupyter_token = jupyter_data["token"]
        except:
            pass

def test_create_directory_in_mynotebooks(cert_path=None):
    time.sleep(10)
    client = requests.session()
    url = JUPYTER_HOST + '/hub/login?next='
    data = {'username': JUPYTER_USER, 'password': JUPYER_PASSWORD}
    response = client.post(url, data=data, verify=cert_path)
    response.raise_for_status()
    content_string = response.content.decode('utf-8')
    parser = TokenParser()
    parser.feed(content_string)
    url = JUPYTER_HOST + '/user/test-bot/api/contents/MyNotebooks'
    data = {'path': 'MyNotebooks', 
            'type' : 'directory'
            }
    token = "" if parser.jupyter_token is None else parser.jupyter_token
    response = client.post(url, json=data, verify=cert_path, 
                                headers={"Authorization": "token "+token}, allow_redirects=False)
    assert response.status_code >= 200, content_string
    assert response.status_code < 400, (str(response.status_code) + " " + str(response.content), content_string)
```

Recently the jupyterhub version switced from 1.5.0 to 2.0.0 and this test doesn't work anymore. The token cannot be found in the page anymore. When I try manually to explore jupyterhub, I also don't find the token. But of course I can create the folder. "jupyter notebook list" returns running notebooks but also without tokens.

What could have happened? Are there significant changes in the jupyterhub_config or maybe environment variables?

Comment: Yes, there were significant changes to access tokens and introduction of RBAC among others. There is [changelog](https://jupyterhub.readthedocs.io/en/stable/changelog.html#id1) and  a blog [post announcement](https://blog.jupyter.org/jupyterhub-2-0-7a038715e96d).

Comment: Ok. I'll work through it and post here the changes in scripts to make it work.